# VisualStudio 2010: Quickly flip between text editor color schemes? (for LCD vs Projector)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, plugins, color-scheme

In VS2010, I have a customized text editor color scheme that has a black background and light grey text. This is great for me working by myself on an LCD display. However, often I need to plug in to a projector to display code to a group. The black background color scheme does not work well at all on a projector, so I always want to flip back to basically the "default" color scheme.

The only way I know of to do this right now is to export the VS color settings to a backup file, then revert to defaults. When I am done with my group presentation, I can then re-import the previously exported color settings.

Does anyone know of an easier / less manual way of doing this? Like a plugin that lets you flip between text editor color schemes, or simply a macro to do the manual process above?

Answer (score 0):

I found this writeup on how to make a macro and menu items to quickly export/import the fonts and colors: http://jeffhandley.com/archive/2010/03/09/225.aspx